# How to compare two double precision real numbers in Fortran?

Tags: floating-point, fortran, compare

I wrote a Fortran subroutine to compute the time of flight(TOF) between two points on elliptical orbit. Obviously this TOF has to be a positive number. I tested my subroutine with different data but in some cases I get negative result despite of I coded a possible way to solve this problem.

Here is my subroutine:

```
!*************************************************************
    subroutine TOF_between_2TA(e,xn,theta1,theta2,delta_t)
!*************************************************************
!  Compute time of flight bewteen two points (point 1 and point 2) on elliptical orbits.
!*************************************************************
!  Input:
!  xn     = mean motion, any units
!  e      = eccentricity
!  theta1 = true anomaly of first point, in interval [0, twopi]
!  theta2 = true anomaly of second point, in interval [0, twopi]
!
!  Output:
!  delta_t = time of flight between two points (same units as given by xn)
!*************************************************************
 
       
        implicit none

        ! Arguments
        double precision, intent(in)  :: e,xn,theta1,theta2
        double precision, intent(out) :: delta_t

        ! Locals
        integer :: i
        double precision               :: xe,sxe,cxe,cth,sth,den,theta
        double precision, dimension(2) :: theta_vec,xm_vec
        
        !! To get positive time intervals, theta_vec must be sorted in ascending order  
        if (theta1 < theta2) then     
           theta_vec = [theta1, theta2]   ! Case theta1 < theta2
        elseif (theta2 < theta1) then 
           theta_vec = [theta2, theta1]  ! Case theta1 > theta2
        endif
        
        do i=1,2          
            theta = theta_vec(i)
            
            cth = cos(theta)
            sth = sin(theta)
            den = 1.0 + e*cth
            cxe = (e + cth)/den
            sxe = sqrt(1.0-e*e)*sth/den 
            xe = atan2(sxe,cxe)
        
            ! atan2 returns angles in interval -pi, +pi, we need angles in interval [0,2pi]
            xe = mod(xe,twopi)
            if (xe .lt. 0.0_pr) xe = xe + twopi 
        
            xm_vec(i) = xe - e*sxe         
            
        enddo
        
        delta_t= (xm_vec(2)-xm_vec(1)) / xn
        
        return
        
    end subroutine TOF_between_2TA
```

Can you suggest me a way to increase the robustness of my soubrutine and protect me against undesiderable result, i.e. negative numbers?
I'm almost pretty sure that the problem is when I try to compare the vatiables theta1 and theta2, what is the smartest way to compare two real numbers?

Edit - After many tests, I report here the working routines:

```
!*************************************************************
    subroutine TOF_since_pericenter(e,xn,theta,delta_t_peri)
!*************************************************************
!  Time of Flight since pericenter: From true anomaly to time
!*************************************************************
!  Input:  
!  xn    = mean motion, any units
!  e     = eccentricity
!  theta = true anomaly, in interval [0, twopi]
!
!  Output:
!  delta_t_peri = time since pericenter (same units as given by xn)
!*************************************************************
 
        implicit none

        ! Arguments
        double precision, intent(in)  :: e,xn,theta
        double precision, intent(out) :: delta_t_peri

        ! Locals
        double precision :: xe,sxe,cxe,cth,sth,xm,den
        
        cth = cos(theta)
        sth = sin(theta)
        den = 1.d0 + e*cth
        cxe = (e + cth)/den
        sxe = sqrt(1.d0 - e*e)*sth/den 
        xe  = atan2(sxe,cxe)
        ! atan2 returns angles in interval [-pi, +pi], we need angles in interval [0,2pi]
        xe = mod(xe,twopi)
        if (xe .lt. 0.d0) xe = xe + twopi 
        
        xm = xe - e*sxe
        delta_t_peri = xm/xn
        
        return

    end subroutine ToF_since_pericenter
    
    
    
!*************************************************************
    subroutine TOF_between_2TA(e,xn,theta_1,theta_2,delta_t)
!*************************************************************
!  Compute time of flight required by point 1 to reach the point 2 on elliptical orbits.
!  The point 1 is the moving object and it rotates counterclockwise on its orbit 
!*************************************************************
!  Input:
!  xn        = mean motion, any units
!  e         = eccentricity
!  theta_1   = true anomaly of asteroid, in interval [0, twopi]
!  theta_2   = true anomaly of intersection point, in interval [0, twopi]
!
!  Output:
!  delta_t = time of flight between two points (same units as given by xn)
!*************************************************************
 
       
        implicit none

        ! Arguments
        double precision, intent(in)  :: e,xn,theta_1,theta_2
        double precision, intent(out) :: delta_t

        ! Locals
        integer :: i
        double precision               :: T,delta_t1_peri,delta_t2_peri
        double precision, parameter    :: small = 1.d-30
        
        ! Compute orbital period
        T = twopi / xn
        
        call TOF_since_pericenter(e,xn,theta_1,delta_t1_peri)
        call TOF_since_pericenter(e,xn,theta_2,delta_t2_peri)
        
        delta_t = delta_t2_peri - delta_t1_peri
        
        if (delta_t .gt. small) then     
           delta_t = delta_t
        elseif (delta_t .lt. -small) then 
           delta_t = delta_t + T
        endif
           
        return
        
    end subroutine TOF_between_2TA
 
!*************************************************************
```

Further comments and improvment suggestions are well accepted.

Comment: What values does theta_vec have when theta1 is equal to theta2? Your logic doesn't handle that case.

Comment: I modified the routine and now it seems to work well. I will update the question with my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do an explicit comparison. You can construct `theta_vec` as

```
theta_vec = [min(theta1, theta2), max(theta1, theta2)]
```

This has the advantage of being branchless, so it will run significantly faster than the comparisons. (Not that this is likely to be relevant to the overall performance of your code).

I should also point out that the lines

```
xe = mod(xe,twopi)
if (xe .lt. 0.d0) xe = xe + twopi
```

can be replaced with

```
xe = modulo(xe, twopi)
```

taking advantage of the fact that the output of `modulo(a, p)` is always non-negative if `p` is positive, unlike the output of `mod`.